Installing Manim crashes my colab notebooks
i am trying to run manim in google colab and used the installation guide which said i need to copy&paste the following:
!sudo apt update
!sudo apt install libcairo2-dev ffmpeg \
texlive texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-extra \

texlive-latex-recommended texlive-science \

tipa libpango1.0-dev

!pip install manim
!pip install IPython --upgrade
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
torch 2.2.1+cu121 requires nvidia-cublas-cu12==12.1.3.1; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64", which is not installed.
torch 2.2.1+cu121 requires nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12==12.1.105; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64", which is not installed.
torch 2.2.1+cu121 requires nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12==12.1.105; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64", which is not installed.
torch 2.2.1+cu121 requires nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12==12.1.105; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64", which is not installed.
torch 2.2.1+cu121 requires nvidia-cudnn-cu12==8.9.2.26; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64", which is not installed.
torch 2.2.1+cu121 requires nvidia-cufft-cu12==11.0.2.54; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64", which is not installed.
torch 2.2.1+cu121 requires nvidia-curand-cu12==10.3.2.106; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64", which is not installed.
torch 2.2.1+cu121 requires nvidia-cusolver-cu12==11.4.5.107; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64", which is not installed.
torch 2.2.1+cu121 requires nvidia-cusparse-cu12==12.1.0.106; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64", which is not installed.
torch 2.2.1+cu121 requires nvidia-nccl-cu12==2.19.3; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64", which is not installed.
torch 2.2.1+cu121 requires nvidia-nvtx-cu12==12.1.105; platform_system == "Linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64", which is not installed.
moviepy 1.0.3 requires decorator<5.0,>=4.0.2, but you have decorator 5.1.1 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed click-default-group-1.2.4 cloup-2.1.2 decorator-5.1.1 glcontext-2.5.0 isosurfaces-0.1.0 manim-0.18.0.post0 manimpango-0.5.0 mapbox-earcut-1.0.1 moderngl-5.10.0 moderngl-window-2.4.4 networkx-3.2.1 pycairo-1.26.0 pydub-0.25.1 pyglet-2.1.dev1 pyrr-0.10.3 screeninfo-0.8.1 skia-pathops-0.7.4 srt-3.5.3 svgelements-1.9.6 watchdog-3.0.0
since it kept completely crashing the sessions i ran every line seperately and the install manim line produces the error posted below. It ran when i just used the direct link to binder but as i mostly use colab thats a little unsatisfying. How can i resolve this?
